# Rename [coded-ui-tests] so it refers specifically to Visual Studio UI tests

Tags: support, tags, tag-disambiguation

Now and than, I come across questions about UI automation using the [coded-ui-tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coded-ui-tests) tag along with [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium), [appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appium), ... tags. This makes perfectly sense, since UI automation deals with coding UI tests.

The problem here is, this specific tag is actually about the [Visual Studio Coded UI tests](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/use-ui-automation-to-test-your-code?view=vs-2019) test framework and has nothing to do with other test frameworks.

If the user asking these questions would read the description, they would know not to use this tag.

Is it possible to change a tag name itself? I've looked into this, but I was only able to edit the tag information.

If possible, please change the tag name so its clear the question is about the Visual Studio test framework and not just about "coding ui tests".

Comment: How correct are the current questions in the tag?  If a significant fraction are off topic the tag would need to be cleaned up first.

Comment: As we speak, for the first 10 questions using [tag:coded-ui-tests], I found 3 using it wrong. Not sure how representative this is. The coded-ui-test framework will be discontinued on the next Visual Studio release (see link in post above). I assume there will be less and less questions about that framework until, at some point, it will only be used wrongly.

Comment: I'm not sure, but 30% would probably require a cleanup first.

Comment: @DanNeely, I did some quick research. I found 43 questions using the selenium and coded-ui-tests tags in combination. Since the selenium tag has 66.9k questions using that tag, I think the actual percentage will be well below 30% for all tags combining with coded-ui-tests tag. 1828 questions use the coded-ui-test tag, 70 questions being asked this year.

Comment: @DanNeely how does a cleanup work? Is there something I can do?

Comment: it's a possible outcome of the [burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination?noredirect=1&lq=1) to review and fix problematic tags.  The process itself has an ~5 year backlog and is effectively on hold because the mod running it (Bhargav Rao) has heavily reduced activity as a result of the Monica fiasco.

Comment: @DanNeely, Oh... that's bad... I didn't know about this crisis yet. I just read up on it, thank you for informing me about it.